# Weird behavior of custom item renderer in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, itemrenderer

I have a class defined like this:

```
public class Photo
    {
        public function Photo()
        {
        }
        public var PhotoId:int;
        public var Title :String;
        public var Subtitle :String;
        public var PhotoByteArray:ByteArray ;
        public var ThumbnailByteArray:ByteArray;
        public var ShowOnlyInFrontpageTop:Boolean;
        public var ShowInFrontpageGroup:Boolean;
        public var BackgroundColorGradientFrom:String;
        public var BackgroundColorGradientTo:String;
        public var IsActive :Boolean;
    }
```

I 'm getting diverse objects of this type (Photo) from a WCF service (works fine!). These objects are stored in an ArrayCollection  defined like this:

```
public static var GroupPhotos:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
```

I want to show up these photos using a s:List component, like this:

```
<s:List height="110" id="GroupPhotos" itemRenderer="MyGroupPhotoRenderer">
                <s:layout >
                    <s:HorizontalLayout requestedColumnCount="3"  />
                </s:layout>
            </s:List>
```

The item renderer is defined this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true"
                creationComplete="onItemrenderer_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            //when the item has been rendered and is ready to be shown the following method will be called
            protected function onItemrenderer_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {               
                img.source =  data.ThumbnailByteArray;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Group id="PhotoGroup" width="297" height="110" >
        <!--<s:Rect id="imgRectangle" alpha="0" width="95" height="65">
            <s:stroke>
                <s:LinearGradientStroke weight="{GroupBoxBorderWeight}" scaleMode="none"/>
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Rect>-->
        <mx:Image id="img"  
                  width="{PhotoGroup.width}" height="{PhotoGroup.height}" 
                  />
        <s:Label id="title"                  
                 fontSize="20" 
                 text="{data.Title}"/>
    </s:Group>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

The s:Label component shows up correctly whereas the mx:Image component shows up always the same image (don't know if this is the first Image or the last in the array).
What am i missing?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ahhm!!Turns out that this my error! Above i stated that the service is running fine: guess what...it didn't! Fixing the service made the images show up correctly!

Comment: Glad to hear you got everything up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Creation complete is only called the first time your renderer is created. Since Flex reuses renderers that means it will only get called the first time. Instead of using `creationComplete`, override the `set data` method of your renderer. Unfortunately, `s:ItemRenderer` doesn't have a `set data` method, so I'd use a `mx:HBox` component instead.

Here's a quick example to get you started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                super.data = value;

                theLabel.text = value["Title"].toString();
                theImage.source = data.ThumbnailByteArray;

                validateDisplayList();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:Label id="theLabel" />
    <mx:Image id="theImage" />
</mx:HBox>
```

Comment: Hi Jason! If interpret correctly what you say, then i should be able (using the s:ItemRenderer) to bind the image this way  <mx:Image id="img"  
                  width="{PhotoGroup.width}" height="{PhotoGroup.height}"  source="{data.ThumbnailByteArray}"
                  />
But this doesn't work: i 'm getting the same result! But i will try what you suggest...and see what happens!

Comment: Another option would be to try overriding the updateDisplayList method in your ItemRenderer to set the values of your label and image. I'm also assuming your Photo class is [Bindable] correct?

Comment: I did some surgery on the server side code (WCF service) and verified that the images are correctly inserted into the DBMS and out of it! I also realized that the last image is always drawn!

Comment: Neither suggestion did work! I don't get it (i have to admit it's my first real world project), but it shouldn't be that tough (or am i wrong?). Try to dig again! Ah!! ...yes the Photo class is [Bindable]!

Comment: Without looking at the rest of your code, I'm not sure what to try next. Perhaps these articles may be of help: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-tutorial-image-itemrenderer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597105/flex-caching-images-in-list-item-renderer and http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/01/cool-itemrenderers-made-easy-in-flex-4/.